# Retrieve claims collection of a given type in ASP.NET-Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have implemented a system where a user is allowed access to a given url is only he has that url in his/her claims. I have create a claim of type "UserRoutes" and add the URLs available to the user. So, when the user logs in to the application, he/she can only visit those URLs in his/her claims of type "UserRoutes".

Now I am looking for a way to fetch that collection of his/her URLs in a view to decide whether or not to display the link to a given url.

Trying this

```
  @if (User.FindAll("UserRoutes").Contains("courses/create"))
    {
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary my-3"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> New Course</a>
    </p>
     }
```

or this

```
var userRoutes = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserRoutes");
if (userRoutes.Contains("courses/create")){
<p>
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary my-3"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> New Course</a>
    </p>
```

shows the following error

> IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Contains(ParallelQuery, string)' requires a receiver of type 'ParallelQuery

Please how can I achieve this. I appreciate your efforts

Comment: You should add a `bool` Property to your Model and assign it from the controller, because the `IEnumerable<T>.Contains<T>(T value)` is located in `System.Linq` namespace, which you don't have referenced (and really, you shouldn't) in your view as `@using System.Linq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `HasClaim` method in which you can pass claim type and value

```
User.HasClaim("UserRoutes", "courses/create")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error message because you need a reference to `System.Linq` because that's where `IEnumerable<T>.Contains<T>(T source)` is located. If you **REALLY** want to have your logic in the view, you should add `@using System.Linq` at the top of the view (or put in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file).

**BUT**

You should really send that kind of logic to the `Controller` / `PageModel` instead of putting it on the view render!

Assuming you're using `RazorPages` with a `RazorPage` named `MyPage`

In `MyPage.cshtml.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
/* this is the key */
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class MyPageModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public bool CreateCourses { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            /* set the property to use on the page */
            this.CreateCourses = User.FindAll("UserRoutes")
                .Any(claim => claim.Value == "courses/create")
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `MyPage.cshtml`:

```
...
@if (Model.CreateCourses)
{
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary my-3"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> New Course</a>
    </p>
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for guiding me to rather add the logic in the controller. That makes sense. However, I have chosen @Kahbazi's answer cos it is quite shorter and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @if (User.Where(p => p.YOURPARAMETER == "UserRoutes").ToList().Contains("courses/create"))
    {
    <p>
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary my-3"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> New Course</a>
    </p>
     }
```

Remember to replace `"YOURPARAMETER"` to element you want to compare.

Comment: Trying to use this, I got the following error:

ClaimsPrincipal does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method accepting a first argument of type ClaimsPrincipal could be found...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Any()` extension method

```
 @if (User.FindAll("UserRoutes").Any(claim => claim.Value == "courses/create"))
{
        ...
 }
```